# Qt/C++ Exited with code -1073741819 (Program crashes with exception code c0000005)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, exception, crash

I'm having trouble with my program crashing. I get that "Program.exe has stopped working" windows pop-up which mentions my exception code is c0000005. When I return to the output from the application in Qt, it shows:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\project\project-build-desktop\debug\project.exe exited with code -1073741819
```

I've found the line that's causing the error (I think!), though I don't know why it might. If I comment out this line, the program won't crash.

The line is:

```
db=newDb;
```

This is located in the constructor of my class `wndChildWhatever` which is a QMainWindow. `newDb` is defined in the constructor arguments as `DatabaseManager *newDb` and `db` is a private member of wndChild defined as `DatabaseManager *db`. This database address is passed around all over my program, and this `wndChildWhatever` is the only one I'm having trouble with.

The exception/crash doesn't occur when the window is opened/constructed, however. It happens when the window is closed. What's weirder is that it doesn't happen every time. Sometimes you can open the window and close it with out problem, then open it again and on the second closing, it crashes. Other times it happens the first time you try to close it.

I'm really not sure what's going on here and hope someone can assist!

Comment: You forgot the towel operator on line 42.

Comment: Run your program in a debugger. It will halt immediately when the AV happens, no guessing involved. It will also provide you with the call stack and probably with local vars, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The faulting line:

```
db=newDb;
```

And you say:

> and db is a private member of wndChild

It sounds like your `this` pointer might be invalid.  That is, if this happens in a method `foo` you are doing something like `wndChild->foo()` and `wndChild` is an invalid pointer.  Therefore when it access the offset of `db` relative to `wndChild` you hit an accesses violation.  (NT error code `0xc0000005`, Windows-speak for a bad pointer dereference.)

Comment: I was thinking that too, except he says his command occurs in the wndChild constructor.  It's not easy to have an invalid this-pointer from within a constructor, I think....

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner - Perhaps his class is allocated on the stack and there is an overflow.

Comment: Or perhaps in some other line he managed to pass `this` to some other piece of code which did a `delete`...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's not the db=newDb line itself that's causing the crash, but rather some other code that gets executed later on, that doesn't get executed if you don't set the db value.  Have a look at the other code inside your wndChildWhatever class, and see what it is doing with the (db) value.  Perhaps it is doing something naughty, like deleting it while other code is still using it?

Comment: The thing is, db isn't being used anywhere in wndChildWhatever yet. I can't use it if I don't have it properly assigned, and assigning it crashes my program. Right now, wndChildWhatever is very simple. I'll keep playing around though, see if I can figure a better source of the problem. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Hmm.  When all else fails, try doing a "make clean; make".  Sometimes a object file doesn't get recompiled when it should have been, and Weird Things Happen (tm)

Comment: I believe this is what happened. I was playing with my code and added a QMessageBox to my wndChild deconstructor to see if the program was crashing in that window's deconstructor or what happens in some other function after deconstruction. When I did that, the program stopped crashing. When I commented out the QMessageBox, and was still getting it! I did a Rebuild All in Qt and haven't had problems since.

Answer (score 0):

With the line db=newDb you have two pointers to the same object. What do you do in the destructors? If you have "delete db" and "delete newDb" you delete the same object twice which may lead to a crash or not.

Answer (score -3):

Try to delete the build directory and rebuild it. It worked for me, but i need to do it everytime I add a new function or member to any class. Idk why.